# Bigcommerce SSL issue

Tags: php, curl, ssl, bigcommerce

I've got the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', True);
 require 'bigcommerce.php';
    use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;


    Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'Our URL is here and valid',
    'username' => 'Our username is here and valid',
    'api_key' => 'Our key is here and valid'
    ));

    Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');    
    Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
}
?>
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message 'SSL peer     certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' in /home/zetaphor/public_html/bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php:82 Stack trace: #0 /home/zetaphor/public_html/bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php(142): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->handleResponse() #1 /home/zetaphor/public_html/bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php(333): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->get('https://store-9...') #2 /home/zetaphor/public_html/bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php(408): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getCollection('/products', 'Product') #3 /home/zetaphor/public_html/bigcommerce-api-php-master/coupons.php(17): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::getProducts() #4 {main} thrown in /home/zetaphor/public_html/bigcommerce-api-php-master/bigcommerce.php on line 82
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out myself.

Had to add the following two lines to the constructor of Bigcommerce.php (The single file version of the API)

```
curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
```

This does present some security issues, but this file will be run locally for a one-off report.